# Change field required property after form load

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form (**A**), one field of which depends on the select value of the second form (**B**).

So I need that field to become required or not, according to what was selected in the select field of **B** form.

Currently I have the field.required set to False in **A** form `__init__` method, and I check the data from **B** form in request by overwriting the clean method of **A**, and make field required if necessary, but that all happens after clicking the submit button. And obviously if the field is now set to required and I change the value of the select field in **B**, I am no longer able to set field to not required in **A**, since it simple doesn't let me click submit.

Is it possible to make it work somehow?

My form:

```
class PublicationCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Publication
    fields = ('title', 'event')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    super(PublicationCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['event'].required = False

def clean(self):
    type = self.request.POST['type']
    if type == 'BOOK':
        self.fields['event'].required = False
    if type == 'CONF':
        self.fields['event'].required = True
```

Comment: Its better to handle this logic in the template in my opinion

Comment: better you use jquery for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this using jQuery in the template with one of the following lines.

```
$('#Your_Input').removeAttr('required');
$('#Your_Button').removeAttr("disabled")
```

Hope it helps.